# Trying to write an short int into buffer start produces strange ouput

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I've been stumped on this issue for a while now, and I can not seem to find a resolution

To briefly describe what I'd like to do.. I'm trying to generate a buffer of random data (to upload as a row into a testing table). However I'm working with a system which requires that I first generate and fill the buffer with data first and then append a 2 byte length specifier at the very beginning of the buffer so that it will know how many bytes it will need to read into the system, then lastly a terminating character at the end.

I have the generators and most of the logic implemented (tested) except I can't for some reason get the two byte length specifier into the start of the buffer correctly.

```
    int generate() {
        char buffer[BUFSIZ];
        memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFLEN);
        unsigned short rec_len = insert_data(buffer);

        //... continue

        return 0;
    } 

    unsigned short insert_data(char* buff_ptr) {
            // Save a pointer to the start of the buffer
            char *sbuff_ptr = buff_ptr;

            // Save space to fit two bytes length specifier to be filled
            // once all my data has been generated and put into the buffer 
            buff_ptr += 2;

            // Set in the two byte record length specifier
            unsigned short rec_len = buff_ptr - sbuff_ptr;
            memcpy(sbuff_ptr, &rec_len, 2);

            // Generate data using self-implemented data generator functions
            // For example, to generate the first data value
            int id = rand_int(0);              // id = 0
            memcpy(buff_ptr, &id, 4);
            buff_ptr += 4;

            // ... This continues on until all required dummy data has been 
            // generated

            // Set in the end of record marker to indicate end of data row
            memset(buff_ptr, '\n', 1);
            buff_ptr += 1;

            // Set in the two byte record length specifier
            unsigned short rec_len = buff_ptr - sbuff_ptr;
            memcpy(sbuff_ptr, &rec_len, 2);

            if (DEBUG) printf("\n\tBUFF_PTR (END):   %p\n", buff_ptr);
            if (DEBUG) printf("\tSBUFF_PTR  (START): %p\n", sbuff_ptr);
            if (DEBUG) printf("\tRECORD_LENGTH:      %hu\n", rec_len);

            return 0;
    }

    Output
    -----------
    BUFF_PTR  (END):   0xffff9169     
    SBUFF_PTR (START): 0xffff90ce
    RECORD_LENGTH:     155       

    // Record Length: Confirmed to be correct (after manually counting up all the bytes
```

However when I try to print out the contents of the buffer as a validation
check to see that the length specifier had been set correctly

```
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < rec_len; i++) {
        printf("\tbyte %d BUFFER's CONTENTS: %d\n", i, buffer[i]); 
    }

    byte 0 BUFFER's CONTENTS: -101    // This should be 155
    byte 1 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0       // End of two byte length specifier
    byte 2 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0       // int id = 0
    byte 3 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 4 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 5 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0              
    byte 6 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 110     // Start of some string value
    byte 7 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 111
    byte 8 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 110
    byte 9 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 118
    ...
    byte 154 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 10   // Correct termination
```

In attempt to debug, I've written a small script that mimics what I want to do, and strangely so, that works... Comparing the two, I can't find the difference

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned short buf_init(char* buffer) {    // -- Following are the digit       
                                // representations of each string character
char* hello   = "hello\0";      // 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0
char* goodbye = "goodbye\0";    // 103, 111, 111, 100, 98, 121, 101, 0
char* who     = "they\0";       // 116, 104, 101, 121, 0       

int a = 19;
float b = 20.5;
short c = 12;

char *bp = buffer;
char *bs = buffer;

// length specifier 
bp += 2; 

memcpy(bp, hello, strlen(hello));
bp += strlen(hello);

memcpy(bp, &a, 4);
bp += 4;

memcpy(bp, goodbye, strlen(goodbye));
bp += strlen(goodbye);

memcpy(bp, &b, 4);
bp += 4;

memcpy(bp, who, strlen(who));
bp += strlen(who);

memcpy(bp, &c, 2);
bp += 2;

// Terminate
memset(bp, '\n', 1);
bp += 1;

// Record Length
unsigned short len = bp - bs;
memcpy(bs, &len, 2);  

printf("rec_len: %hu\n", len);

return len;
}


int main(void) {
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    memset(buffer, '\0', BUFSIZ);

    unsigned short len = buf_init(buffer);

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("\tbyte %d BUFFER's CONTENTS: %d\n", i, buffer[i]); 
    }

    return 0; 
}


/*  --OUTPUT
    rec_len: 29
    byte 0 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 29        // Correct Length Specifier
    byte 1 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 2 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 104       // "Hello"
    byte 3 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 101
    byte 4 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 108
    byte 5 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 108
    byte 6 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 111
    byte 7 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 19
    byte 8 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 9 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 10 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 11 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 103
    byte 12 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 111
    byte 13 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 111
    byte 14 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 100
    byte 15 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 98
    byte 16 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 121
    byte 17 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 101
    byte 18 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 19 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 20 BUFFER's CONTENTS: -92
    byte 21 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 65
    byte 22 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 116
    byte 23 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 104
    byte 24 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 101
    byte 25 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 121
    byte 26 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 12
    byte 27 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 0
    byte 28 BUFFER's CONTENTS: 10  // Terminates correctly with an new line
*/
```

Would anyone like to offer their advice?

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored just right. The problem lies in the way you output your data. You try to output the buffer, which uses single `char`.

Since you are on a little endian system, the byte order of your short will be reversed. Meaning the least significant byte will be first. Judging from your code, the type `short` is two bytes on your system. The value 155 will be stored completely in the least significant byte, which will then be located in the first byte of your buffer due to it being located first in memory.

Next you output the buffer. This buffer uses single `char`. A `char` may be either signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. On your implementation, it appears to be signed. The value of 155 is represented in memory as follows (assuming a 2's complement 8-bit system):

10011011

As you can see, the first bit is set. In a 2's complement system, this means the value is negative for a signed type. Since a `char` appears to be signed on your system, this same sequence that would be 155 in unsigned representation, means -101 as a signed value. You then print this value, which results in the value of -101 you see.

The value you used in your check is below 127, meaning the sign bit will not be set, and the value will be printed as expected. If you make your test message longer than 127 bytes, you will see a negative value again due to the way a 2's complement system works.

You could solve this problem by casing the type char to unsigned char to make sure you print them as unsigned. Also, don't forget to edit your printf modifier to represent an unsigned type, instead of a signed one. That way you will see your expected output.